# Bubble Sort in C

Tags: c, sorting

I am trying to implement Bubble sort in C and have come this far but its nor sorting properly.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i, j, a[5], b, temp;
    printf("Enter the number of elements to be sorted\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d - Enter the elements - ", i);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < n+1; ++j)
        {
            if(a[i] > a[i+1])
            {
                temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
2
12
1
13
```

**Output**

```
2
1
12
13
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Just an FYI, you have one major flaw in your program. You ask the user how many elements they will be entering, but you initialize your array prior to that. This can lead to an index out of bounds exception if someone enters a number greater than 5. Cheers.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an explanation. I hope you also fix the issue I noted in my previous comment. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So now that the drama is behind us, the problem with your code was that you were not using the proper index in your inner loop.  In addition your inner loop counter's conditional check was not correct.  Also, as I mentioned in a comment to your question, you have a flaw in your code (which I have not fixed) where you initialize your array prior to asking the user how many elements they want to enter.  This can lead to an index out of bounds exception if the user enters a number greater than 5.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i, j, a[5], b, temp;
    printf("Enter the number of elements to be sorted\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d - Enter the elements - ", i);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < n-1; j++)
        {
            if(a[j] > a[j+1])
            {
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j+1];
                a[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually prefix versus postfix makes no difference in for loops. How a for loop executes follows 4 different steps.
First: Execute the first of three statements inside the for loop.
Second: Check if the second statement in the for loop evaluates to true, it will continue execution
Third: Run the body of the for loop.
Fourth: Execute the third statement in the for loop. Usually this is something along the lines of '++i' or 'i++'

Comment: @Cairnarvon Why do you think, its not worth upvoting ?

Comment: @rcomp When I wrote that, and when it was upvoted, his answer was that the third part of the loop should use a post-increment rather than a pre-increment, which is beyond ridiculous. (As it currently stands, it's still a pretty bad answer in that it's just a code dump rather than an explanation, but at least it technically works.)

Comment: @rcomp, originally when Sly Raskal uploaded it, it was functionally equivalent to the source provided in your question. Also being the Sly Raskal he is, he has edited his answer as each new answer to your question has come along, making his answer eventually correct.

Comment: @Cairnarvon, i am typing on an iPad which is annoying to me to say the least. I edit my posts as I go along, but wanted to get the code in there as fast as I could before someone else had the code posted. I was planning on updating the post with textual information to help the OP. Cheers.

Comment: @Cairnarvon, in case you didn't notice, I also left a comment on the question regarding a flaw. I found on his program. I am here to help, as well as learn myself. Please be patient with members of this board instead of being so aggressive. Cheers.

Comment: @Loothelion, if you pay close attention to the edit history, you will see my edits to make it correct were prior to the other good answers, minus the plagiarized one. As Sly as I want to be, I can't fudge the timestamps on SO. ;)

Answer (score 2):

your second loop is not proper.

```
for(j=0;j<n-i-1;j++){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/*By your approach , in inner loop you are not checking the each elements . So change i to j in swapping , and limit of j should be till n-1*/


  #include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int n, i, j, a[10], b, temp=0;
printf("Enter the number of elements to be sorted\n");
scanf("%d", &n);
for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    printf("%d - Enter the elements - ", i);
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
}
for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    for(j = 0; j < n-1; ++j)     // notice limit , also complexity can be reduced by changing        to(j<n-i-1)
    {
        if(a[j] > a[j+1])
        {
            temp = a[j];        // changed variable 
            a[j] = a[j+1];
            a[j+1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    printf("%d\n", a[i]);
}
return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/*You May check this code it will help you*/
#include<stdio.h>
void bubble_sort(int a[],int n);
void bubble_sort(int a[],int n)
{
    int i,j;
    int temp;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<=n-i-1;j++)
        {
            if (a[j]>a[j+1])
            {
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j+1];
                a[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }

    }
}
main()
{
    int a[10];
    int i,n;
    printf("Enter the number\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter the number\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    bubble_sort(a,n);
    printf("sorted elements are\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%d\n",a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   #include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
           int n, i, j, a[5], b, temp;
            printf("Enter the number of elements to be sorted\n");
           scanf("%d", &n);
           for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
           {
                 printf("%d - Enter the elements - ", i);
                 scanf("%d", &a[i]);
             }
          for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
           {
                    for(j = 0; j < n; ++j)
                     {
                          if(a[j] > a[j+1]) //change the varible instead of i to j
                          {
                                 temp = a[j];
                                 a[j] = a[j+1];
                                 a[j+1] = temp;
                            }
                   }
            }
            for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            {
                  printf("%d\n", a[i]);
             }
             return 0;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

**I've tried to cover all possible conditions to reduce passes and comparisons for bubble sort to reduce the overall time taken. Here goes my code...**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void bubbleSort(int n){
    int arr[n],i,j,temp=0;
    int swapFlag = 0;

    printf("\nInsert %d elements:\n",n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    printf("Insert complete.\n\n");

    printf("Your array looks like:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }

    //Bubble Sort Algorithm
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        swapFlag = 0;
        for(j=0;j<n-i-1;j++){
            if(arr[j]>arr[j+1]){
                swapFlag = 1;
                //Swapping unordered pairs
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
        //Condition to reduce number of passes & comparisons
        if(swapFlag == 0){
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("\n\nAfter sorting the array looks like:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
}

void main(){
    int n;
    printf("Enter number of array elements: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    bubbleSort(n);
    getch();
}
```

**Result:-**

[image: Bubble Sort Implementation]