# bubble sort arrays in c

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have already researched this topic, especially [Bubble Sort in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21508381/bubble-sort-in-c).
I am working on the bubble sort algorithm with arrays, I understand the concept if I draw it but when it comes to implementing the loops I am lost; From how I'm understanding I know one loop is the amount of passes and the other loop for the swap. I'm getting confused  with all the variables and loops...could someone clarify the looping part for me? If anyone knows any well versed video tuts for this topic please msg them to me!! I tried to break down each step in chunks so I could follow it better but
I'm going to annotate in my code what I do not understand. Thx for the help as always

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main (void)
    {
    int a[20], i, j, temp;
    int SIZE= 20;<==== A[20] SPECIFIES 20 ELEMENTS IN MY ARRAY and I HAVE INT SIZE = 20, can I just pick one or the other for use as the variable?

  //ask user to enter 20 numbers for the array's elements
   printf("Enter the elements be sorted");
   scanf("%d", &SIZE);
   for(i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);

   //bubble sorting<========I'M COMPLETELY LOST HERE
   for(SIZE-2;i<20; i--){
    for(j=0;j<=i;j++){
      if(a[j]>a[j + 1]{
         temp = a[j]
            a[j] = a [j+1];
            a[j+1]= temp;
    }
    }
    }
    printf("After sorting: ");
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    printf(" %d", a[i]);
    }
    }
```

Comment: `for(SIZE-2;i<20; i--){` is wrong.

Comment: Ok, I just changed to i++. Can you explain why it's not i--? I'm still having problems with loop concepts so i'm struggling lol

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: thx, that's helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lyZQPjUT5B4
This explains with funny way !

Comment: thank you, i'm a visual learner, thanks again I'm just trying to get the concept down, I appreciate you not biting my head off