# Pass pointer of array to function that sorts numbers

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I'm new to C and cannot figure out how to pass a pointer of an array to a function. The function should sort user input numbers in ascending order. I think I've missed something crucial in the function.

I'm able to input the user values but that's as far as I've been able to get without errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sort(int *p, int i); //function declaration
int main()
{
    int numbers[10]; // ten element array
    int i;

    printf("Please enter ten integer values:\n");
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
        scanf("%d", (&numbers[i]));

    int *p= &numbers; //a pointer that points to the first element of number
    sort(int *p, int i); //function

}

//function sorts in ascending order
int sort (int *p, int i) //function definition
{
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) //loop through entire array
    {
        printf("%d\n", *p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Same mistake of everyone, ignoring the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: Do you write `scanf(const char *"%d", int *&numbers[i]);` to call `scanf`? No. Just like you don't write `sort(int *p, int i);` to call `sort`.

Comment: what @immibis is trying to say is that your call to function `sort()` on line 12 is wrong. it should not re-declare the types of the variables, just use them directly, like this: `sort(p,i);`

Comment: Note also that your for loop inside sort will just print the first element of the array 10 times.  You should change the print statement to: printf("%d\n", p[i]);

Comment: @bruceg thanks, it appears to print in descending instead of ascending..was there a mistake in the function?

Comment: @taji not sure what you mean.  Your sort function doesn't actually sort anything, right?  It just prints out the contents of the array in the order that you typed them in.

Comment: @bruceg it's actually printing in descending order right now but i'm going for  ascending.

Comment: @taji your sort function as written above doesn't sort the array.  All that it does it try and print out the elements.  You actually need to implement a sort algorithm.  Perhaps you should read this article to understand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21508381/bubble-sort-in-c

Comment: @bruceg gotcha, thanks.

Comment: `int *p= &numbers;` should be `int *p = &numbers[0];`  as your comment explains. Your compiler should report this mistake - pay attention to compiler messages.

Comment: @Taji you should read more about functions, specially, when the Function should be of type int or void.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write

```
int *p= numbers;//a pointer that points to the first element of number
    sort(p, i); //function
```

An array passed to a function is converted implicitly to pointer to its first element.

Also the function should look like

```
//function sorts in ascending order
int sort (int *p, int n) //function definition
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++) //loop through entire array
    {
        printf("%d\n", *p++);
        // or
        //printf("%d\n", p[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So why not `sort(numbers, i)` ?

Comment: @WeatherVane In this case he will not know how to declare correctly the pointer.:)

Comment: The function `sort` only prints the same array element unless it does `printf("%d\n", *p++);` or `printf("%d\n", p[i]);`

Comment: @Taji You have to sort the array. You can either write your own sort function or use standard C function qsort.

Answer (score 0):

> A pointer is a variable which contains the address in memory of
>   another variable. Ampersand `(&)` operator denotes an address in
>   memory.
>
> `int *p= &numbers;` this line will hold the first address of the array
>   element. For printing every element of an array you have to increment
>   the pointer `printf("%d\n", *p++);` and when you call a function you
>   don't need to declare it's argument data type. In this line `sort(int
>   *p, int i);` this is a wrong way to calling a function.just call them directly, like this way: `sort(p,i);` in your case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sort(int *p, int i); //function declaration
int main()
{
    int numbers[10]; // ten element array
    int i;

    printf("Please enter ten integer values:\n");
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
        scanf("%d", (&numbers[i]));

    int *p= &numbers; //a pointer that points to address of the first element of numbers array
    sort(p, i); //function

}

//function sorts in ascending order
int sort (int *p, int i) //function definition
{
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) //loop through entire array
    {
        printf("%d\n", *p++);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This sort function is just printing the value.If you want the complete code Go [here](https://ideone.com/13atlV)